# Jackson deserialization bellow JSON property

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I want to `fetchMultiple(ParameterizedTypeReference<List<T>> responseType)` for a given `List<T>`, in this case, I want to get directly a `List<Account>` but I am getting an error because the list of accounts is encapsulated in another object, as shown below:

```
{
    "accounts": [
        {
            "accountUid": "c75deb59-5d52-4a23-af7b-fce29927ce9d",
            "defaultCategory": "b4189da5-7688-42d0-86e3-14ae9031e01d",
            "currency": "GBP",
            "createdAt": "2020-08-05T16:50:50.536Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

There is some Jackson annotation to filter this somehow in order to be processed like this:

```
[
    {
        "accountUid": "c75deb59-5d52-4a23-af7b-fce29927ce9d",
        "defaultCategory": "b4189da5-7688-42d0-86e3-14ae9031e01d",
        "currency": "GBP",
        "createdAt": "2020-08-05T16:50:50.536Z"
    }
]
```

POJO

```
@Data
public class Account {

    private String accountUid;
    private String defaultCategory;
    private String currency;
    private String createdAt;

}
```

*RestRequestTemplate.java*

```
public List<T> fetchMultiple(ParameterizedTypeReference<List<T>> responseType) {
        return new RestTemplate().exchange(this.url, this.httpMethod, this.request, responseType).getBody();
}
```

*AccountsServiceImpl.java*

```
public List<Account> getAccounts() {
   RestRequestTemplate restRequestTemplate = new RestRequestTemplate(GET_ACCOUNTS, HttpMethod.GET, Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
   return restRequestTemplate.fetchMultiple(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Account>>() {});
}
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason to have List<T> as the parameter in the fetchMultiple(ParameterizedTypeReference<List<T>> responseType) method? If not, we can change it to just fetchMultiple(ParameterizedTypeReference<T> responseType)

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<com.starlingbank.challenge.roundup.model.accounts.Account>` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]

Comment: I am looking to have `List<T>` as a parameter because I am looking for a generic solution if  instead, I have `T` as parameter I will need to instantiate `AccountResponse`, the implementation is something like this:

public List<T> fetchMultiple(ParameterizedTypeReference<T> responseType) {
        AccountResponse response = (AccountResponse) new RestTemplate().exchange(this.url, this.httpMethod, this.request,responseType).getBody();
        return (List) response.getAccounts();
}

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed an annotation to ignore the root object. It is called `@JsonUnwrapped`. Annotate your method with that annotation and your `json` should be without the root object.